# is there a way to check if cloud firestore API is enabled or propagate error if not?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a public npm package that uses Firebase and Firestore. Developer who uses my package, can insert the project details to the module, and then it uses them to create user accounts, store some data on Firestore.

I encounter a problem where when the developer who uses this package has enabled Firebase project BUT has not enabled Firestore in their project.

My expectation is that if Firestore is not enabled, it should return error during initialization or return error if user attempts to use API such as `updateDoc`. From `firebase/firestore` npm package in javascript. (Browser environment)

However, what I'm experiencing right now is that, application hangs upon calling `updateDoc` even if I use `try/catch` or `.catch((e) => {...})`.

Initially I had no visibility on what's going on, so I have been doing some research to get some idea what's going on and find out that I can use `setLogLevel('debug');` to show more details.

After enabling the debug, I start seeing messages on my browser console with messages like:

> Cloud Firestore API has not been used in project XXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firestore.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"

But what I want to see is that this error gets propagated during the use of API or initialization. (above error message is prompted through internal Firestore lib)

Couldn't capture the error with two different approaches

```
try {
      const res = await setDoc(doc(this.firestore, `/users/${this.userUid}/devices`, key), {
        ... some details
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('e', e);
    }
```

```
return setDoc(doc(this.firestore, `/users/${this.userUid}/devices`, key), {
        ... some details
      }).catch((e) => {...})
```